# Is adding a tickbox that does nothing !ifempty bad or clever?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, css

I have a very bespoke system that we will use internally to track payments.

I have an input box, and if the user leaves it blank (Does not know X), it inserts "Awaiting X" into a database instead of the X.

The idea i have to stop the user fill in either variations of NONE or N/A or some random string of text all the time is that they click a tick box "Not known yet?" and it addes 0.4 opacity to it with jQuery or something - therefore leaving it blank.

Is this bad practice or clever mini-validation?

I welcome any clever ideas for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On the database side**
It is good practice to use `null` *(not the string `'null'`, but the database concept null)*. Into a database to signal the fact that there is no data.
So I would advice not to use `'awaiting this or that'`, but just use `null`.

In a database you can select these rows like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name IS NULL
```

**On the UI side**

I like your idea.
Do do hope that if and when I select the editbox, I can just fill something in without having to untick the checkbox by hand.

Comment: Yeah, the addition of clicking the input box is nice. It'd essentially be faux disabled, and I can get away with such things because we have such a small team here.